# Mysql condition on WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I m using mysql database using php to fetch data. I have distributor column, i m using WHERE clause like WHERE d_id = 1 . i have 1 to 4 distributors.  On front end i have HTML select option in which if i select any distributor it shows it's data but i added an option value="0" as Total . Now if i select Total it should show all data, actually where clause should not work then. (show all distributors data)

```
    Dist:  Product    Sales 
1.  dis_a    abc         100
2.  dis_b    abc         50
3.  dis_c    cde         10
4.  dis_c    cde         10
```

Comment: So what is your question? If you want to to select all distributors, just omit the `WHERE` clause when the selected ID is 0

Comment: @Remy Lebeau yes, but how? what should i change in where clause?

Comment: @user3030814 they are saying just omit the WHERE clause entirely when the code that executes the query sees a 0. Alternatively, `WHERE ? IN (d_id, 0)` should work as well. _(where ? is the parameter value)_

Comment: @Uueerdo `WHERE ? IN (d_id, 0)` - This looks nice, but can probably not use an index.

Comment: i used this WHERE ? IN (d_id, 0) but it is not showig the right answer

Comment: Prepare the sql with or without the where clause **IN PHP** that is where you know about the value of the variable, so act accordingly.

Comment: Are you creating the query from a client language like PHP? See for how to build a `WHERE` clause dynamically based on the input parameters.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yeah, definite downside; but I was trying to prevent them from having to use the parameter twice in `WHERE ? = 0 OR d_id = ?` where one would hope short circuit evaluation stopping at the constant expression would effectively remove the WHERE clause for them.

Comment: Simply i want to make WHERE clause silent when d_id = 0. Notice: there is no d_id = 0 in database, d_id are 1 to 4

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a select that should do roughly what you want.

```
select d.[disc:], d.[Product], d.[Sales]
from your_table d
where d.your_table_seq =  case when @dist_id = 0 then d.your_table_seq else @dist_id end
```

The case block will allow you pull every row when the @dist_id parameter is equal to 0, but will only pull id's that are equal to @dist_id when @dist_id is not equal to 0.

Comment: That's T-SQL syntax, not MySQL.